# Simplest Content Management Framework

Tags: php, content-management-system

I have never worked with a content management framework. From my understanding a CMF would enable easier management of database tables, concepts, entities. Also with ability of viewing lists with pagination, etc.

Which would be the simplest CMF to start/expirement with (in PHP) ?

Answer (score 1):

I find [MODx](http://modx.com/) a great, easy to learn, CMF.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a shot today. And is it free ?

Answer (score 1):

When I started out learning about CMF/CMS, I found [this site](http://www.phpframeworks.com) to be very helpful. There are a lot of frameworks out there and most of them usually will fit you needs. But there are about a thousand ways to go when it comes to CMF/CMS and this should fit your style of coding. Especially when you are not really into MVC coding, then you will probably have to compromise with the framework you will be using. The easiest would be wordpress of course, but that would be an understatement to what you are probably planning.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I do work extensively on Wordpress. But what I am looking for is complete control over the interface layer (file names, structure, etc).
And yes, would not want to work with the MVC concept.

Comment: Although you wouldnt want to work in MVC, I highly recommend using it as it has a well defined structure in code and folders. You will need to do a bit of work to understand and afterwards you will be just fine!

Comment: I completely understand the advantage of MVC, very well versed with it. There is just a particular scenario I am trying to find a solution for. Thanks for the link, going through them all.